# Azure storage non Classic (V2) - How to configure custom domain

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

In new Azure portal there are 2 storage account: non classic and classic account.
as I think the classic is old version then I choose the non classic.

The problem is, I cannot configure the custom domain on the new portal, it redirected me to the old azure portal (manage.windowszuare.com) .

and the problem continue.. the old azure portal not recognizing the new/nonClassic Azure storage.

Kindly advise, how can I configure the custom domain for storage blob V2 (non classic).

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like right now the new portal does not have a way of doing that. It's on their backlog though, so stay tuned!

For now to unblock you: The best way to edit custom domain would be through [Powershell](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell) or [Xplat CLI](https://github.com/Azure/azure-xplat-cli). In Powershell you'll want to use 'Switch-AzureMode AzureResourceManager' to use the new type of storage accounts. This flag will be deprecated soon and you'll default to the new stuff, but for now that's how to do it. Then, you'll then need to use the SetAzureStorageAccount command which will allow you to modify custom domain.

Comment: Thank you Emily, I think I wait for the improvement of the new portal and the new storage account. I need to use the custom domain on ssl and that is not possible for now.. so I skip the custom domain. :)

Comment: Hi @Emily Gerner - Microsoft, I don't see in [Set-AzureStorageAccount documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495306.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) how it will allow to modify custom domain. Could you please extend your _how-to_? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @IagoRodríguez-Quintana You're looking at the Service Management docs rather than the Resource Management docs. Service Management is the old stuff. Try [Set-AzureStorageAccount documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt125934.aspx)

Comment: @EmilyGerner-Microsoft, thank you very much. I can see it now.

Comment: For anyone reading this in future, the correct command for the post-`Switch-AzureMode` world is `Set-AzureRmStorageAccount`.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the custom domain by clicking on your storage account, clicking on All Settings, and choosing Custom Domains from there.

But if something does sometimes kick you back to the "old" portal, don't worry too much. It's all the same data and account. The Preview Portal is still a preview portal and may be missing a few features. 
Showing up as "storage account (classic)" is normal even if you make a brand new account if you are using Storage Blob.

Comment: Thank you amanda.. yes if we use the classic storage account we can set the custom domain via portal. but it won't work for the non classic account.

Comment: Yeah I guess that particular option isn't in the new portal - I see that now - they'll probably keep updating it. Good luck!