# Azure Resource Manager Deployment vs Classic Deployment of Storage Accounts

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to understand the differences between Azure Resource Manager Deployment vs Classic Deployment of Azure Storage Accounts:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-manager-deployment-model/

So from what I can gather, if I use the Azure Resource Manager (ARM) deployment method to deploy a storage account (v2), I would loose the ability to:

1. Use a table storage container as a storage location for Web App
   diagnostics. This is because I am only able to enable diagnostics
   through the old portal and it does not appear to recognize the ARM 
   v2 storage account.
2. The ability to create CDN endpoint based on a `Storage Accounts` origin type. It's the same scenario again; the old portal does not
   recognize the newer storage account type.

So at least for the moment,  these constraints are forcing me to use a (classic) storage account in order to use the above features. Have I understood this correctly or am I missing something?

Comment: What do you mean by, "create CDN endpoint based on a storage account's origin type?"

Comment: @ShaunLuttin This is what I meant by creating a storage account based CDN endpoint: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cdn-create-new-endpoint/

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32117912/azure-storage-non-classic-v2-how-to-configure-custom-domain/

Comment: Thanks @EmilyGerner-Microsoft . So I guess I've got to stick to the classic storage account type until the v2 version is supported by the above features.

Comment: Since it looks like my comment answered the question for you, I've posted it in actual answer form to make it a bit easier for other folks to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new portal does not have a way of doing either of these things right now, but they are in the backlog. Both should be accomplishable using the client libraries (available in .Net, Node, and Java) or the command line tooling available through [Powershell](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell) or [Xplat CLI](https://github.com/Azure/azure-xplat-cli).

See also: [Azure storage non Classic (V2) - How to configure custom domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32117912/azure-storage-non-classic-v2-how-to-configure-custom-domain/)